# Directory.CreateDirectory creating a folder which cannot be accessed by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Following code is used to create a new folder in the project directory:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create(Item model)
{
    string s = model.Category.Name;
    if (ModelState.IsValid && model.imageUpload != null && model.imageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string initialPath = string.Format("~/Images/Products/" + s + "/"); 
        var virtualPath = Path.Combine(initialPath, model.imageUpload.FileName); 
        var d = Directory.CreateDirectory(string.Format(Server.MapPath(initialPath)));             
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(model.imageUpload.FileName);
        var validImageTypes = new[] { ".gif", ".GIF", ".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".pjpeg", ".PJPEG", ".png", ".PNG" };
        if (!validImageTypes.Contains(extension))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("imageUpload", "Please add a valid format picture (i.e., a .gif,.jpg or .png image");
            return View();
        }
        model.imageUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(virtualPath));
        model.imageUrl = virtualPath;

        db.Items.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["name"] = model.ItemName;
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
    model.Categories = new SelectList(db.Categories.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
    model.Brands = new SelectList(db.Brands.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
    return View(model);
}
```

Code runs like a shine and creates the desired folder under the desired directory. Problem currently arising is when reading from the newly created folder, Visual studio is unable to read from the folder and browser is throwing a 404 (file not found) error while reading from it.

Is it to do with permissions? I checked newly created folder permissions and those are set to 'Full Access' for 'Everyone'.

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Post code you use to read from the folder? My bet is you have the path wrong...

Comment: visual studio can read path if it's correct.

Comment: @Milney - Above code is shown only for the creation of the folder. I'm reading into the folder from a GET method in a `View`.

Comment: @KiranJoshi - Browser is rendering the correct path but with error that file from within the folder cannot be accessed.

Comment: @Milney https://ibb.co/ivWPF9

Comment: @KiranJoshi https://ibb.co/ivWPF9

Comment: have you refreshed your page?

Comment: Have your file is saved local folder ?

Comment: Refreshing the page solved the situation. Thanks @KiranJoshi

Comment: @Dad any time. it's happening because of the browser give a page from cached so at that time file is not found there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a static file handler for that path - If it is under the path of your web application then IIS will not serve static files as it is a security risk.

Either replace the URL of the file with an Action which reads the file and returns it - or add a static file handler to your web.config for that path.